# Prove this alternative formula for derivative $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

Show that:

$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x + h) - f(x - h)}{2h} \tag 1$$

*Proof:*

If $(1)$ is true then $f'(x) = \displaystyle \frac{f(x + h) - f(x) + f(x) - f(x - h)}{2h} = \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{2h} - \frac{f(x - h) - f(x)}{2h}$

But here is the confusion, how do I modify the $f(x- h)$ on the RHS? **PLEASE ONLY SMALL HINTS! I want to do this mostly on my own!**

Thanks =)

Comment: Factor the $\frac{1}{2}$ and write the second term as $+\frac{f(x+(-h))-f(x)}{(-h)}$.

Comment: You can calculate the limit of each term seperately and in the second computation you replace $h$ with $-h$ (both go to $0$ as $h$ goes to $0$)

Comment: just use $u=-h$ in the second fraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x) + f(x) - f(x - h)}{2h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{2h} - \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x - h) - f(x)}{2h}$$

In the second limit make a change of variables $u=-h$ to obtain:

$$= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{2h} - \lim_{u \to 0}\frac{f(x + u) - f(x)}{-2u}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} + \frac{1}{2}\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{f(x + u) - f(x)}{u}=\frac{1}{2}f'(x)+\frac{1}{2}f'(x)=f'(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$2f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{x+h-x}+\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{x-(x-h)}$$

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite the fraction $-\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}$ as $\frac{f(x+(-h))-f(x)}{-h}$.

Then it will get clear where this fraction converges to, when $h$ approaches zero.

Comment: But how does: $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + (-h) - f(x)}{-h} = f'(x)$

Comment: If $h$ approaches zero, so does $-h$. You should not get confused by the sign. $h$ approches zero from both sides, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

$\tiny\text{Hint: remeber that} \lim_{h\to+0} \ldots = \lim_{h\to-0} \ldots \text{ because of continuity.}$

Comment: that is not small enough.